# Best parent layout for this interface?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to figure out the best parent layout to build this interface with.

[image]
Here are some additional information/ requirements:

A) The ViewGroup that contains everything.

B) MapView that fills the available vertical spacing

C) RecylcerView that scrolls a list of item horizontally. Has a fixed height (i.e. 200 dp)

D) FloatingActionButton that sits on top of View B + C. It's anchor on the top right of View C.

I tried a lot of different options for **View A**, but they don’t seem to work.

- **LinearLayout**: LinearLayout has no notion of a Z index so
  FloatActionButton get's cut off.
- **RelativeLayout**: RelativeLayout has no notion of "fill in remaining vertical space" so the MapView's height is not dynamic and needs to be fixed
- **FrameLayout**: Same issue as RelativeLayout.

Also, when the user taps on the FloatingActionButton, I'll need to inject fragment modal into this activity, so it'll be place over this current layout.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably something like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout_a"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/layout_c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/layout_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_c"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_d"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: for the transition to a new screen you have lots of options.   You can launch a new activity,  start a DialogFragment or add a framelayout to the Relative layout that fills the whole screen.

Comment: Thanks man! I guess the key here was the `android:layout_above` property for the mapView, which allows it to fill the vertical spacing!